# Implementing STL list copy constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl

I'm trying to implement a STL list's copy constructor. I am confused whether my implementation is correct or not. Can someone help me to see if there is anything missing from my copy constructor?

```
  List::List(const List &rhs)
  {
    if(!empty())
      clear();
    delete head;

    head = new Node(0);
    head->next = head;
    head->prev = head;
    _size = 0;

    if(!(rhs.empty()))
    {
      Node* head_ptr = head;
      for(Node* now = rhs.head->next; now != rhs.head; now = now->next)
      {
        Node* newNode = new Node(now->data);

        if(now->next == rhs.head)
        {
          head->prev = newNode;
          newNode->next = head;
        }

        head_ptr->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = head_ptr; 
        head_ptr = head_ptr->next;       

        _size++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Code explanation:

1. empty() = is a function that checks whether the list's size is zero or not.
2. clear() = is a function that deletes all the nodes in the list, but leaving the dummy value not deleted.

Comment: The class is being constructed so the empty check is not needed.

Comment: So I just need to directly clear it ?

Comment: Just delegate to your default constructor see __Delegating constructor__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor